# PHP Separate two different sections in one input

Tags: php, regex, split

I'm working on a PHP based application extension that will extend a launcher style app via the TVRage API class to return results to a user wherever they may be. This is done via Alfred App (alfredapp.com).

I would like to add the ability to include show name followed by S##E##:
example: Mike & Molly S01E02

The show name can change, so I can't stop it there, but I want to separate the S##E## from the show name. This will allow me to use that information to continue the search via the API. Even better, if there was a way to grab the numbers, and only the numbers between the S and the E (in the example 01) and the numbers after E (in the example 02) that would be perfect.

I was thinking the best function is `strpos` but after looking closer that searches for a string within a string. I believe I would need to use a regex to correctly do this. That would leave me with `preg_match`. Which led me to:

```
$regex = ?;
preg_match( ,$input);
```

Problem is I just don't understand Regular Expressions well enough to write it. What regular expression could be used to separate the show name from the S##E## or get just the two separate numbers?

Also, if you have a good place to teach regular expressions, that would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex:

```
$text = 'Mike & Molly S01E02';
preg_match("/(.+)(S\d{2}E\d{2})/", $text, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mike & Molly S01E02
    [1] => Mike & Molly 
    [2] => S01E02
)
```

---

If you want the digits separately:

```
$text = 'Mike & Molly S01E02';
preg_match("/(.+)S(\d{2})E(\d{2})/", $text, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mike & Molly S01E02
    [1] => Mike & Molly 
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 02
)
```

---

### Explanation:

**. -->** Match every character

**.+ -->** Match every character one or more times

**\d -->** Match a digit

**\d{2} -->** Match 2 digits

The parenthesis are to group the results.

[www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place to learn regex.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. Thank you so so so much! Time to read up on regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it around and use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to look for the last space in the string and then use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get two strings based on the position you found.

Example:

```
$your_input = trim($input);    // make sure there are no spaces at the end (and the beginning)
$last_space_at = strrpos($your_input, " ");
$show = substr($your_input, 0, $last_space_at - 1);
$episode = substr($your_input, $last_space_at + 1);
```